# How to resend dio request, Cancel Previous request and send again in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, request, dio

```
  final client = Dio();

  Future<Voice> getData() async {
    final url = 'url';

    try {
      final response = await client.get(url);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Voice.fromJson(response.data);
      } else {
        print('${response.statusCode} : ${response.data.toString()}');
        throw response.statusCode;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

How can I cancel the previous request and send again, I have a checkbox, Upon checking and unchecking I send requests with different parameters, but the problem is when user check & uncheck  5,10 times quickly application does not work because API request again and again without handling previous one, I want to handle it by cancelling previous request and sending again,  no matter how quick he checks & unchecks checkbox I would cancel previous request and send again so in that way application would work fine and would give result according to current state of checkbox, please guide

Your valuable time and guidance will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you send the request, you can specify the cancellation token (learn more about it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#cancellation) and with [this](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/cancel_request.dart) example), but honestly, before you go into cancelling the requests, I'd think about either of the following:

- redoing the UI in a way so that the user cannot do check-uncheck the checkbox quickly or
- regoing the logic in a way that the request goes out only when the whole form/page is filled/completed or
- redoing the logic in a way that the data is available in advance and changing the UI would only cause the local changes.